# Selecting all files with a specific name and excluding in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know of a way to massively exclude specific files from a c# project?  I don't want to delete them, and I know I can set their individual properties to hidden or alter the filename with a .exclude extension, but I want to know if their is a way in Visual Studio to do this.

For example, if I have 1000 directories with filename img.jpeg, I want to exclude that file from every directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove them from your project (without deleting the actual file), open the .csproj file with an editor that can do search and replace a little better than notepad (wildcards at least) and delete the entries for these files. Save the .csproj file and reopen in Visual Studio.

Note: Visual Studio is a pretty good editor for this, since it also has a good and fast multi-file search&replace. You just have to open the .csproj as text file instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: Looks like this is much better than my powershell script :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write an app or Visual Studio plugin to exclude the files from the projects.  Personally I would just create an app that do the following:

1. Recursively find all .csproj files in your code tree
2. Open the cproj file by loading it into an XmlDocument object
3. Use XPath (e.g. XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode()/SelectNodes()) to find the tag of the file in question.
4. Remove the node and save the file back out to disk using XmlDocument.Save

So it would make a section that looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="licenses.licx" />
   <EmbeddedResource Include="img.jpeg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="licenses.licx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Sample XPath Code to find node:

```
XmlDocument csprojDoc; // this is the document you loaded your csproj XML into
XmlNamespaceManager xnm; // you'll need to build one of these because csproj files use namspaces in the XML

XmlNode excludeNode =
   csprojDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:ItemGroup/ns:EmbeddedResource[@Include='img.jpeg']", xnm);

excludeNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Remove(excludeNode);
```